# ggplot2 get rid of confidence interval

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using the "ggplot2" package in R.

```
ggplot2::mpg


A tibble: 234 x 11
   manufacturer model      displ  year   cyl trans      drv     cty   hwy fl    class  
   <chr>        <chr>      <dbl> <int> <int> <chr>      <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>  
 1 audi         a4           1.8  1999     4 auto(l5)   f        18    29 p     compact
 2 audi         a4           1.8  1999     4 manual(m5) f        21    29 p     compact
 3 audi         a4           2    2008     4 manual(m6) f        20    31 p     compact
 4 audi         a4           2    2008     4 auto(av)   f        21    30 p     compact
 5 audi         a4           2.8  1999     6 auto(l5)   f        16    26 p     compact
 6 audi         a4           2.8  1999     6 manual(m5) f        18    26 p     compact
 7 audi         a4           3.1  2008     6 auto(av)   f        18    27 p     compact
 8 audi         a4 quattro   1.8  1999     4 manual(m5) 4        18    26 p     compact
 9 audi         a4 quattro   1.8  1999     4 auto(l5)   4        16    25 p     compact
10 audi         a4 quattro   2    2008     4 manual(m6) 4        20    28 p     compact
# … with 224 more rows
```

I am using the mpg data in R. I am having trouble making a scatterplot and removing the confidence interval from the regression line I am adding to my scatterplot.

```
When I use the see =FALSE, I get Warning message:
Ignoring unknown aesthetics: se
```

Here is my code, and the attached picture is an example of how I am trying to visualize the data.I have the points but cant get the regression line figured out with the "se" argument. I have used se =FALSE, method=lm etc. Thanks

```
ggplot(data=mpg)+
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x=displ, y=hwy))+
  geom_smooth(mapping=aes(x=displ, y=hwy, color=drv, se=FALSE))
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMqqJ.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to suppress the confidence interval visualization, the code to add is `se = FALSE` indeed. This is however not an "aesthetic" and thus should not be within the aesthetics' definition. An alternative solution is the one provided by @Aite97.

The following code will do the trick.

```
ggplot(mpg) +
  geom_point(aes(x = displ, y = hwy))+
  geom_smooth(aes(x = displ, y = hwy, color = drv), se = FALSE)
```

This yields the following graph:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I missed putting "se" outside of the "aes ()". In my code, if I have the color in the aesthetic function as "drv" which gives me a green, red and blue line. What if I wanted to make all three of the regressions lines blue while keeping the "color=drv argument"?

Comment: This is a new question; but here we go anyhow. One way is to replace `color = drv` by `group = drv`. You can set the color **outside aes**, with e.g. `color = "darkred"`. Let me know whether this is what you were after, please.

Comment: Apologies, for the extra question. I was wondering about this. This is what I was after and you answered my question about it. Thank you! `ggplot(data=mpg)+
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x=displ, y=hwy))+
  geom_smooth(mapping=aes(x=displ, y=hwy, group=drv), color="blue", se=FALSE)` That is the code I used.

Comment: My pleasure, I am glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

a solution would be to replace se = FALSE with level = 0.
Level is the confidence level, and setting it to 0 fixes the problem:

```
ggplot(data=mpg)+
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x=displ, y=hwy))+
  geom_smooth(mapping=aes(x=displ, y=hwy, color=drv), level = 0)
```

Comment: Running your code generates a warning similar to the OP's, because you make the same mistake: `level` is also not an "aesthetic".

Comment: Both se and level seem to be valid inputs, but only level worked for me. However, I see that I accidentally typed level inside mapping, but it's supposed to go outside the mapping. I'll fix